# Quantum perturbation theory recommendations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, perturbation-theory

What are some concise resources, in particular, online resources, for perturbation theory in quantum mechanics? I want something like a crash course to perturbation theory in quantum mechanics that is easy to understand (let's exclude [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_%28quantum_mechanics%29)).

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/81142/2451

Comment: Note that res. recom. qs are restricted on Phys.SE and they usually do not distinguish between on-line and off-line resources.